# Can I emulate Multiple Class Inheritance with Decorators?

Tags: javascript, class, decorator, multiple-inheritance

a class overwrites the properties of the class it is extending :

```
class ClassA {
  msg = 'ClassA'
}

export default class ClassB extends ClassA {
  msg = 'ClassB'
  onClick() {
    console.log(this.msg) // will log "ClassB"
  }
}
```

a decorator overwrites the properties of the class it is decorating :

```
function ClassA(BaseClass) {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    msg = 'ClassA'

  }
}

@ClassA
export default class ClassB {
  msg = 'ClassB'
  onClick() {
    console.log(this.msg) // will log "ClassA"
  }
}
```

extending multiple classes is not allowed - you cannot do (pseudocode):

```
export default class ClassC extends [ClassB, ClassA] {}
```

but you can do:

```
   @ClassA
   @ClassB
   export default class ClassC {}
```

The problem with the above is that the "extension" is reversed. The `decorators` will overwrite any properties that `ClassC` has defined. But I don't want that.

In other words, I want to use `decorators` to emulate multiple class extension but I don't want my `decorators` to overwrite any properties that the decorated class has already defined.

I could do the following:

```
function ClassA(BaseClass) {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
      super(...arguments)
      if (!this.hasOwnProperty('msg')) {
        this.msg = 'ClassA'
      }
    }
  }
}

@ClassA
export default class ClassB {
  msg = 'ClassB'
  onClick() {
    console.log(this.msg) // will log "ClassB"
  }
}
```

but this is too verbose.

Imagine a class with many properties, some of which are even decorated themselves. Having to implement the above solution below seems unsustainable:

```
function ClassA(BaseClass) {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    msg = 'ClassA' // this should "register" for ClassB, not for ClassC

    @service('x') aa // this should "register" for ClassC, not for ClassB

    @computed('aa')
    get bb() { // this should "register" for ClassC, not for ClassB
      return this.aa + 5000
    } 
  }
}

@ClassA
export default class ClassB {
  @service('y') aa
  
  @computed('aa')
  get bb() {
    return this.aa + 3
  }
}

@ClassA
export default class ClassC {
  msg = 'Class C'
}
```

Is there a easier way of having a decorator not overwrite the properties of the class it is decorating if they already exist?

Or is what I'm trying to achieve impossible?

**Note 1:** I do not want to use class extension because I want to extend multiple classes which is impossible so the idea is to use multiple decorators as a workaround

**Note 2:** Please do not suggest multiple class extension examples. I've seen them all and they are all pretty hacky and only work with very basic simple classes with primitive properties, not with classes which themselves contain decorated properties, complicated methods, other class instances etc..

**EDIT:**
I just thought of this solution but have yet to test it. It's meant to emulate multiple class extension (ClassA, ClassB) using decorators, while at the same not allowing the decorators to overwrite properties that ClassC has already defined:

```
@ClassA
@ClassB
class MyDecorators { /* empty on purpose */ }

export default class ClassC extends MyDecorators {}
```

Comment: It's not `class ClassC extends ClassB and ClassA {}`. It's `class ClassC extends (class ClassB extends ClassA {}) {}`.

Comment: I don't want to define class B as an extension of Class C etc... All 3 classes are distinct classes not extending anything during their declaration. My "chained" example was just pseudocode to illustrate that multiple inheritance in that way is impossible and therefore I need another workaround and I was thinking about decorators. Maybe I should've illustrated that with `class C extends [ClassX, ClassY, ClassZ, ....] {}` - all classes in that array being distinct and not extending anything in their own declarations.

Comment: @Kawd ... regarding _"Think of them as 'mixins'"_ ... why are you not going then to implement a mixin based approach via, e.g. function based mixins? One easily could implement them with a more trait-like behavior where one would prevent the overwrite of already existing properties and/or methods at such a mixin's apply time.

Comment: Because I find decorators (or class inheritance) a lot cleaner to write and use, whereas with "mixins" they are not aware of the "context" so you need to do a lot of extra stuff to make them work. Traditional class extension or decorators sort of work "out-of-the-box". My only problem is the overwrite of properties with decorators, but if there is no solution, I'll end up going for the "ugly" (more or less) mixins.

Comment: "*All 3 classes are distinct classes not extending anything during their declaration.*" - then this is impossible.

Comment: I added a possible solution at the end of the OP

Comment: @Kawd ... If you make your scenario more clear by providing other, more to the point, example code (like base functionality with properties / methods and the to be mixed in behavior), I might be able to prove that function-based mixins out of the box, by their very nature, are context aware and even could be implemented with additionally shared private/protected state.

Comment: Instead of creating a `MyDecorators` class, you should just write `class C extends ClassB(ClassA()) {}`

Comment: Thanks @PeterSeliger - I will do so as soon as I find some more time to write up a complete use-case.

Comment: @Bergi your `ClassB(ClassA())` seems to imply that there is custom logic in `ClassB` that expects `ClassA` to be passed to it if I'm not mistaken ? Never seen this before (!)

Comment: @Kawd No. It's just a function expecting an optional class to be passed, similar to a decorator. Same for `ClassA()` - they could be used as `ClassA(ClassB(null))` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem so I'm posting it here in case it helps.

```
function decoratorB(BaseClass) { // Class B
  return class extends BaseClass {
    unchangedClassBproperty = 'unchanged Class B property'
    originallyDefinedByClassB = 'originally Defined By Class B'
    originallyDefinedByClassC = 'overwritten by Class B'
  }
}

function decoratorC(BaseClass) { // Class C
  return class extends BaseClass {
    unchangedClassCproperty = 'unchanged Class C property'
    originallyDefinedByClassC = 'originally Defined By Class C'
    originallyDefinedByClassD = 'overwritten by Class C'
  }
}

function decoratorD(BaseClass) { // Class D
  return class extends BaseClass {
    unchangedClassDproperty = 'unchanged Class D property'
    originallyDefinedByClassD = 'originally Defined By Class D'
  
    showInheritance() {
      console.log('unchangedClassAproperty = ', this.unchangedClassAproperty)
      console.log('unchangedClassBproperty = ', this.unchangedClassBproperty)
      console.log('unchangedClassCproperty = ', this.unchangedClassCproperty)
      console.log('unchangedClassDproperty = ', this.unchangedClassDproperty)
      console.log('originallyDefinedByClassB = ', this.originallyDefinedByClassB)
      console.log('originallyDefinedByClassC = ', this.originallyDefinedByClassC)
      console.log('originallyDefinedByClassD = ', this.originallyDefinedByClassD)
    }
  }
}

@decoratorB
@decoratorC
@decoratorD
class ClassesBCD {}

class A extends ClassesBCD {
  unchangedClassAproperty = 'unchanged Class A property'
  originallyDefinedByClassB = 'overwritten by Class A'
}

const a = new A()

a.showInheritance()
```

will log:

```
  unchangedClassAproperty = unchanged Class A property
  unchangedClassBproperty = unchanged Class B property
  unchangedClassCproperty = unchanged Class C property
  unchangedClassDproperty = unchanged Class D property
originallyDefinedByClassB = overwritten by Class A
originallyDefinedByClassC = overwritten by Class B
originallyDefinedByClassD = overwritten by Class C
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0khsndfg/)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a chain of you class instances and access them through a proxy and inside the traps you can implement any logic you want:

```js
class ClassA {
  msg = 'ClassA'
}

class ClassB {
  msg = 'ClassB'
  logMessage() {
    console.log(this.msg) // will log "ClassB"
  }
}

class ClassC {
  msg = 'ClassC';
}

class ClassD {
  logMessage(){
    console.log('CLASS D LOGGING MSG:', this.msg);
  }
}

function multi(...classChain){ // add support of arguments if needed
  return new Proxy(classChain.map(x => new x), {
    get(target, prop){
      for(const child of target){
        if(prop in child){
          return child[prop];
        }
      }
    },
    set(target, prop, value){
      for(child of target){
        if(Object.hasOwn(child, prop)){
          child[prop] = value
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

const obj = multi(ClassC, ClassB, ClassC);

obj.logMessage();

const obj2 = multi(ClassD, ClassB, ClassC);

obj2.logMessage();
```

Comment: @Kawd if the answer will get useful, don't hesitate to upvote or even accept it, thanks